# Copy all table data and table structures from one user into an another user

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I don't know much about database administration. My problem is i have a oracle database in which we have a user "**user1**" with some tables, In those tables some of them have data, and some don't. Now I want to create a new user "**user2**" and this should be exact replicate of "**user1**". So I exported the user1 like the following:

```
exp user1/***** file=exp.dmp log=exp.log
```

Now I am importing this file into my new **user2** like this

```
imp user2/**** file=exp.dmp ..
```

But it is creating tables which has data only, in **user2**. I want to replicate the all objects from **user1** to **user2**. Please help me on this.
FYI I am using oracle 11g on window 7 applied patch2

Comment: What is the output of the log file?

Comment: it is showing successfully imported without any warnings

Comment: the export log file is what I'm interested in.

Comment: Also, on the exp command are you showing us all of the options you are defining?

Comment: i tried expdp instead of exp it is giving success.  exported "USER1"."USER_MASTER"              13.07 KB       2 rows
. . exported "USER1"."ACTIVITY"                     0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "USER1"."ALTERNATE_NIIN"               0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "USER1"."ALTERNATE_NIIN_OLD"           0 KB       0 rows  after this i used impdp like this. D:\oracle\admin\ORA11G\dpdump>IMPDP USER2/PASSWORD FROMUSER=USER1 TOUSER=USER2 DUMPFILE=HICS.DMP LOGFILE=IMP_HICS.LOG. It also give success. my log file data is  imported "use2"."USER_MASTER"            13.07 KB   2 rows ... and success

Comment: EXPDP AND IMPDP ARE SUCCESSFUL but when i query the DB form list of tables it is giving o rows. I am querying db like this. Select TABLE_NAME from dba_tables where owner='USER2'

Comment: SOLVED MY PROBLEM BY USING A CORRECT SYNTAX OF EXPDP AND IMPDP. I CHANGED LIKE THIS `EXPDP system/**** SCHEMAS=USER1 DUMPFILE=EXP.DMP.. ` AND `IMPDP system/**** REMAP_SCHEMA=USER1:USER2 SCHEMAS=USER1 DUMPFILE=EXP.DMP ....` FIRST I CREATED USER2 AND GAVE DBA PERMISSIONS. THANKING YOU ALL TO HELP ME ON LEARNING A NEW CONCEPT.

Comment: Please create an answer for this question yourself and mark it as correct, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are using [deferred segment creation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#CEGJHDEB)?

Export [will not work](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:3014631100346711923) with tables that don't have a segment.  You'll probably want to use Export DataPump instead.

Or you may be able to get it to work by manually creating a segment:

```
alter table your_table_name allocate extent;
```

Comment: My problem is solved when i use data pump. can you explain the segment concept what you have given. thanks...

Comment: All the data for an object is stored in a segment.  In older versions of Oracle, segments were always created at the same time as objects.  This usually only wasted a trivial amount of space, but in some cases it could be significant.  With deferred segment creation, the segment is not be created until it is truly needed.  I don't know the internals of `imp/exp/impdp/expdp`, but my guess is that exp still assumes there will always be a segment.  Perhaps it uses an inner join somewhere instead of an outer?  `allocate extent` forces creation of the segment, making the table visible to `exp`.